# How to create a figure with caption in Jade

Tags: node.js, html, pug, figure, reveal.js

I'm using reveal.js to create a presentation and I'd like it to include figures and figure captions.  Here's a slide that I'm trying to make:

```
section
  h2 Slide title
  figure
    img(src="images/image.png" align="right" width="70%")
    figcaption Here are some details about the image.
```

Unfortunately this just renders the image with the caption appearing as a `p` element.  Anyone know how to correctly create figures with captions in Jade?

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way to do it in Jade, as you can see from the output HTML. You just have to use some custom styling (CSS or otherwise) to make it look prettier.

Answer (score 0):

just change this:

```
figcaption Here are some details about the image.
```

to this:

```
figcaption = Here are some details about the image.
```